# Gtk does not detect the window either in fullscreen or unfullscreen

Tags: c, gtk

Here is a piece of my project ... and i have a problem with the fullscreen function:

```
#include "header.h"

gboolean  my_gtk_key_press_event(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventKey *event, gpointer data)
{
  GdkWindow *window = gtk_widget_get_window(widget);

  GdkWindowState state = gdk_window_get_state(GDK_WINDOW(window));

  switch(event->keyval) {
  case GDK_KEY_F11:
    if(state == GDK_WINDOW_STATE_FULLSCREEN) {
      gtk_window_unfullscreen(GTK_WINDOW(widget));
    }
    else {
      gtk_window_fullscreen(GTK_WINDOW(widget));
    }

    printf("win_state %d\n", state);
    printf("gdk_state %d\n", GDK_WINDOW_STATE_FULLSCREEN);

    break;
  case GDK_KEY_Escape:
    destroy(NULL, NULL);
  break;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  GtkWidget *win;
  char *s = "In progress";

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  win = win_principal(win, s, 600, 400, 10);

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(win), "key-press-event", G_CALLBACK(my_gtk_key_press_event), NULL);

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(win), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(destroy), NULL);

  gtk_widget_show_all(win);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

When in unfullscreen it prints 128 while in fullscreen it prints 144
And the value of GDK_WINDOW_STATE_FULLSCREEN is equal to 16 ...
how can I solve this problem? Or what is wrong?

Comment: The difference is 16. Does that ring a bell? While [GdkWindowState](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Event-Structures.html#GdkWindowState) is an enum, it might as well be used as a bit flag. But I didn't check how this is expected to work.

Answer (score 1):

GDK_WINDOW_STATE_FULLSCREEN is a bit flag, so, you cannot compare the state directly as you are doing but do a bitwise operation.

Change:

```
if (state == GDK_WINDOW_STATE_FULLSCREEN)
```

To:

```
if (state & GDK_WINDOW_STATE_FULLSCREEN)
```

Here is your code, without dependencies:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

gboolean  my_gtk_key_press_event(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventKey *event, gpointer data)
{
  GdkWindow *window = gtk_widget_get_window(widget);

  GdkWindowState state = gdk_window_get_state(GDK_WINDOW(window));

  switch(event->keyval) {
  case GDK_KEY_F11:
    if (state & GDK_WINDOW_STATE_FULLSCREEN) {
      gtk_window_unfullscreen(GTK_WINDOW(widget));
    }
    else {
      gtk_window_fullscreen(GTK_WINDOW(widget));
    }
    break;
  case GDK_KEY_Escape:
    gtk_main_quit ();
  break;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  GtkWidget *win;
  char *s = "In progress";

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  //win = win_principal(win, s, 600, 400, 10);
  win = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW(win), 640, 400);

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(win), "key-press-event", G_CALLBACK(my_gtk_key_press_event), win);

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(win), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  gtk_widget_show_all(win);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

Compile with:

```
gcc -o window window.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

The window will toggle Fullscreen with F11 and close with Esc.

Comment: Doing so is better: gboolean state = ( gdk_window_get_state(GDK_WINDOW(window)) & GDK_WINDOW_STATE_FULLSCREEN ); ?

Comment: As it is becomes more explicit for the future readers. You get the state and check if the bit is set or not. You can suppress that step in your personnal code as you suggested.

Comment: @Sciamano please note that the result ain't boolean. The value will be 0 or 16 because the bit is not the first one. Obviously it works as there is no boolean type in C. To be more correct you should do:  `gboolean state = ( gdk_window_get_state(GDK_WINDOW(window)) & GDK_WINDOW_STATE_FULLSCREEN ) >> 4;`. Anyway, testing for != 0 would suffice. So we could write:  `gboolean state = ( gdk_window_get_state(GDK_WINDOW(window)) & GDK_WINDOW_STATE_FULLSCREEN ) != 0; Good luck`

Comment: @JoséFonte: `gboolean state = ( gdk_window_get_state(GDK_WINDOW(window)) & GDK_WINDOW_STATE_FULLSCREEN );` **does** yield a boolean! C does have a boolean type, `_Bool`, since C99. In C, any scalar expression that yields a zero is considered *False*, and nonzero *True*. If you want to **enforce** the result to be a C boolean, use the not-not operator: `gboolean state = !!( gdk_window_get_state(GDK_WINDOW(window)) & GDK_WINDOW_STATE_FULLSCREEN );` or `#define BOOLEAN(expr) (!!(expr))` and `gboolean state = BOOLEAN( gdk_window_get_state(GDK_WINDOW(window)) & GDK_WINDOW_STATE_FULLSCREEN );`.

Comment: @NominalAnimal i wasn't being specific on C99. There are issues around that are not related to the question. In fact gboolean is a int and the expression as i said would evaluate nonzero as true. But thanks for your contribution though.

Comment: @JoséFonte: No, but at least I honestly admit when I make mistakes. (You can see many of my admitted mistakes recorded in comments to my answers; whenever I believe something to be a fact, I say whether that is based on facts (in which case I supply links or references), or only my belief. I do make a lot of errors, but thing is, I don't try to hide them; those who come here to seek answers, should have something better than *Social Cues* (like profile pictures) to evaluate the worth of individual answers.)

Comment: @NominalAnimal This is not the place for this kind of flame wars. you are talking about what? if i say C and i meant Ansi C but i was not specific about that then you come here and you think that everyone that says C should mean C11 and everyone must think like you? What about a common denominator? Your simple explanation that C11 has a Boolean (_Bool) type should be enough if there was a lack of specificity.  So why the need to all this rage when there's nothing to rage about... only the lack of specificity... man it's friday... relax

Comment: @JoséFonte: I just don't like slick people providing bad advice to learners, and refusing to admit to any kind of mistakes or errors. When allowed in science, the quality of the research in that field drops like a stone. (In certain fields it is a serious problem already: articles cluster, only referring each other, with no "outside" references; echo chambers full of bullshit.) Sure, I'm an outlier and a grumpy stickler here, but all I care about is the quality of answers and advice, because it affects the next generation of programmers.

Comment: @JoséFonte: Also, I'm not here for any kind of personal glory or satisfaction (except for seeing others learn, and hopefully build wonderful, robust programs in the future); it is a huge part why I participate here only using a pseudonym, and not my real name. I only value the work, not the people.

Comment: Sciamano sorry for the spam. @NominalAnimal i'm here thinking if i should answer you but better not. Sorry if you don't like me, nothing i can do about that. Just can say that you have issues that you must solve and here it's not the place to get help. Good luck.

Comment: @JoséFonte: When you cannot counter the arguments, blame the messenger.

Comment: @NominalAnimal I don't need arguments to rebate you wonderful affirmation: "gboolean state = ( gdk_window_get_state(GDK_WINDOW(window)) & GDK_WINDOW_STATE_FULLSCREEN ); does yield a boolean!" Lets decompose what you have said. gboolean is a int, defined as a typedef. get_state function returns 144 and GDK_WINDOW_STATE_FULLSCREEN its a bit flag with the value of 16 when set. So you are saying that int state = 144 & 16; which means that state = 16 or 0 if the bit ain't set it's a boolean... Right. It does evaluate as true or false but does not yield a boolean. Go parachute jump somewhere else.